# Will I have to pay duty on silver brought into the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

We are travelling to the UK for a three-year stay and not able to get a clear idea of how many silver items  can be carried without paying duty fees. We are planning to take the following: all mentioned are general silver just 4 years old. No antique stuff, and it will leave with us at the end of our stay.

1. Silver lamp, small (2)
2. Small silver cups (3)
3. Silver spoon

Comment: You will need to know the value of the silver objects. At least weight them and find out the silver value for them, and expect the customs in the UK to know they are worth more. We can not help you with just this kind of vague description. One small cup is worth ten times more than one other small silver cup.

Comment: All these would not cross 200 grams

Comment: Weight is not the only consideration, the value of a newly made piece may be low compared to a 300 year old antique, or a cup form a prestigious designer worth more than one brought in a local silversmiths workshop.

Comment: Weight does set a floor on value, but not a ceiling. The items cannot be worth less than their weight in silver, but could be worth a lot more.

Comment: Are you intending to leave these as gifts, or are you taking them back when you go?

Comment: @andrewlazarus : we will take it back when we leave the country. (*In 3 years)

Comment: @Ragav You will have to pay duty if it is over the exemption amount.

Comment: It looks like you are moving to the country, not just visiting. The regime is usually quite different in those circumstances, but it is out of scope for travel.SE. The question should be asked on expatriates.stackexhange.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you and your personal, household property meet various qualifications, no duty will be due. Read more in the Answer to [this SE:Expatriates thread](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/how-will-uk-customs-charge-me-if-i-bring-my-household-goods-to-uk) which cites and discusses [HMRC Notice 5 - Transfer of Residence](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/notice-5-transfer-of-residence-moving-to-or-returning-to-the-uk-from-outside-the-eu/notice-5-transfer-of-residence-moving-to-or-returning-to-the-uk-from-outside-the-eu).