# How/Will UK customs charge me if I bring my household goods to UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, customs

I am going to move to UK from Iran and I want to bring my own furnitures, home appliances, carpets and ecetera with my self.

I have found a company here which can deliver them by Liverpool port, but they say I have to deal and pay possible Customs duty.

Does UK customs charge me for my own stuffs while none of them are brand new?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in a twisty maze of HMRC notices, all different.  Eventually, with luck, you will get to [Notice 5: Transfer of residence from outside the EU](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/notice-5-transfer-of-residence-moving-to-or-returning-to-the-uk-from-outside-the-eu/notice-5-transfer-of-residence-moving-to-or-returning-to-the-uk-from-outside-the-eu)

There are a number of conditions (you must have owned the goods for six months, you must be planning to keep them for the next 12 months, etc, etc), but basically: you should qualify for transfer of residence relief, which means you don't have to pay import duty.

I encourage you to read the linked notice because you need to check all the other conditions, and you need to fill out the paperwork to claim the relief.